# Why are some applications visible in the Finder but are not really there?

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem, ventura

MacOS 13 (Ventura) seems to have a mechanism whereby applications (and I assume folders in general) can appear to be in a given location when viewed in the Finder, yet be located physically elsewhere when other programs look in that location. Here is a concrete example: when I look in /Applications using the Finder, I can see the QuickTime Player application:

[image]

But if I go into the terminal and `ls` in /Applications, it is not there:

[image]

This is not a problem with Terminal; I can look in /Applications using other programs such as Emacs, and they don't "see" QuickTime Player in that folder either. It's also not a problem of user identities; if I `su`, I still don't see it in /Applications.

What is happening? What is the mechanism by which QuickTime is simultaneously there and not there?

Comment: It's to do with the System volume being signed & sealed. Native apps are in Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications , but Finder 'magics' them to the same place as user-installed apps /Volumes/Macintosh HD Data/Applications [or just /Applications]. I'm sure there's a QA already here covering this, but my search-fu is failing me right now.